# How to load a DBF file within a zip file to a variable without extracting it in Python?

Tags: python, zip, dbf, python-zipfile

I am trying to load a DBF file that is contained within a zip file into a variable without extracting the zip file. I have tried using the following code, but it is not working:

```
import zipfile
from dbfread import DBF

def load_dbf_from_zip(zip_filename):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'r') as z:
        dbf_filename = z.namelist()[0]
        with z.open(dbf_filename) as f:
            dbf = DBF(f)
    return dbf

dbf = load_dbf_from_zip('my_zip_file.zip')
```

This code is not working because it is trying to read the DBF file from the zip file using the DBF constructor, which expects a file object as input. However, the open() method of the ZipFile class returns a ZipExtFile object, which is not a file object.

How can I load the DBF file into a variable without extracting the zip file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't. The library you are using [expects a *filename*](https://github.com/olemb/dbfread/blob/ae9890fa5c319fb9dcf4d3be8f0d024df3c52bfc/dbfread/dbf.py#L79) as first argument to `DBS()`, then tries to open and read the file itself. Moreover, the `DBS` class seems to open and read the file multiple times in internal functions, so you can't just create a temporary file and delete it after instantiating `DBS(filename)`. Pretty silly unfortunately.

You will have to either extract the file to disk or create a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), write data to it and pass its name to `DBS`. That file should lives as long as the `DBS` class you work with though.

Overall, I would say this library offers a pretty poor interface, the underlying file could even change and the library will re-open it after it has changed, which I am not sure is something one would normally expect.